# VHDL: Setting upper bits of variable to zero during assignment with shorter variable

Tags: vhdl

When one has something like

```
    variable a    : unsigned (3 downto 0);
    variable b    : unsigned (1 downto 0);
```

and one wants to assign the lower `b'length` bits of `b` to `a`, is it necesary to do

**a)**

```
a(a'left downto b'length) := (others => '0');
a(b'length -1 downto 0)   := b;
```

or can the same be achieved with

**b)**

```
a                       := (others => '0');
a(b'length -1 downto 0) := b;
```

or is there

**c)**

even a more elegant way? 
Option a) seems to work, but everytime I want to use it, I get a bad feeling that this might not be the proper way to do it.

Comment: Another  `A := (a'left downto b'length => '0') & b;`

Comment: With numeric_std `a := RESIZE(b, a'length);`

Comment: okay, but what about assigning `(others => '0')` to the variable `a` before assgning the variable `b` to the lower part of `a`? Will the unaffected bits still keep their `'0'` values?

Comment: The last VHDL assignment always overrides all previous assignments. The a(b'length -1 downto 0) := b only affects the lower bits, so the upper bits stay at 0 from the (others => '0')

Comment: `subtype anotb is unsigned (a'high downto b'high + 1);` ... `a := anotb'(others => '0') & b;` The subtype is globally static as is the aggregate.